# Find substrings of certain length

Tags: prolog

I'm a beginner at prolog and I'm having trouble getting started with the following problem:

> Define the predicate `partstr/3`, where the first argument is a list, that generates a list `A` of length `L` that you find consecutive in the first list.
>
> You should be able to present all answers with backtracking.

E.g.:

```
?- partstr([1, 2 , 3], L, A).
```

If `L` = `2` then `A` = `[1,2]` and `[2,3]`,
or if `L` = `2` then F=[1,2] and [2,3].
and so on...

I feel like you would use recursion to solve it, but I'm not sure where to start. I would really appreciate some tips on how to solve this because I feel like I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Some tips: use length/2 and append/3 to solve this problem. Maybe also between/3 (not sure if you need it).

Comment: Another tip: you should be able to find a working solution by just searching the internet. Not sure why you didn't show your research in this question.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you may only need append/3 and nothing else.

Comment: @TA_intern , now I am curious about how to do that without using `length` or `take` (or some custom predicate that counts down from `L`).

Comment: Hello @yzarc! I have a few questions: what does `F` mean in the example you gave? Is `L = 2` repeated on purpose?

Comment: @salva now that I think about it maybe not possible without length/2. But since the problem statement is botched I don't feel like writing any code. Sorry if I confused you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of this problem is that you need a way to pull all the sublist of length `N` from a list, correct?

So...

- Consider that `append/3` can concatenate two lists: `append( [a,b,c], [1,2,3], L)` returns `L` as `[a,b,c,1,2,3]`. But it can also *decompose* a list into a prefix and a suffix, so

  ```
  append( Pfx, Sfx, [a,b,c])
  ```

  will, on backtracking, successively yield:

  | Pfx | Sfx |
  | --- | --- |
  | `[]` | `[a,b,c]` |
  | `[a]` | `[b,c]` |
  | `[a,b]` | `[c]` |
  | `[a,b,c]` | `[]` |
- ...and... `length/2` can not only tell you the length of a list, but
  can generate lists of a specified length populated with unique,
  unbound variables, so `length(L,3)` returns `[V1,V2,V3]`.

You can combine those to get the behavior you want:

```
partstr( Xs, N, SL ) :- % To get all the contiguous sublists of length N from Xs...
  append(_,Sfx,Xs) ,    % - repeatedly get all possible suffixes of Xs, and...
  length(SL,N) ,        % - construct an empty, unbound list of the desired length (N), and...
  append(SL,_,Sfx)      % - pull that prefix off the suffix
  .                     % Easy!
```

That's one approach. I imagine that this is coursework and that your instructor likely would like you to roll your own solution from scratch.

To do that, we first need a predicate that will yield the source list, and on backtracking remove the head of the list. Something like:

```
suffix( Xs     , Xs  ) .
suffix( [_|Xs] , Sfx ) :- suffix(Xs,Sfx).
```

Then we need a way to grab the 1st *n* elements from a list, something like this:

```
take( _      , 0 , []      ) :- ! .
take( [X|Xs] , N , [X|Sfx] ) :- N1 is N-1 , take(Xs,N1,Sfx) .
```

Given those two...

```
partstr( Xs, N , SL ) :-
  suffix(Xs,Sfx),
  take(Sfx,N, SL )
  .
```

You can even dispense with the `suffix/2` predicate, thus, rolling its functionality into `partstr/3` itself:

```
partstr(    Xs  , N , SL ) :- take(Xs,N,SL).
partstr( [_|Xs] , N , SL ) :- partstr(Xs,N,SL).
```

And that, I think, is the sweet spot: it is hard to beat 4 lines of code —

```
partstr(    Xs  , N , SL ) :- take(Xs,N,SL) .
partstr( [_|Xs] , N , SL ) :- partstr(Xs,N,SL) .

take( _      , 0 , []      ) :- ! .
take( [X|Xs] , N , [X|Sfx] ) :- N > 0 , N1 is N-1 , take(Xs,N1,Sfx) .\
```

Comment: (Do you have "Sfx" and "Pfx" the wrong way around in your table header?)

Comment: Tee-hee :) . . . so I do. Fixed it for you.